# Apply str title to df columns values from dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary that maps column names to a function name. I have wrote a function that should capitalize the values in the df column with `str.title()`

```
import pandas as pd
 
data= [["English","john","smith","ohio","united states","","","manufacturing","National","Residental","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

  Communication_Language__c firstName lastName state        country company email       industry System_Type__c AccountType customerSegment Existing_Customer__c GDPR_Email_Permission__c
0                   English      john    smith  ohio  united states                manufacturing       National  Residental
```

```
def capitalize (column,df_temp):
    if df_temp[column].notna():
        df_temp[column]=df[column].str.title()
    return df_temp

def required ():
    #somethin
    Pass

parsing_map={
"firstName":[capitalize,required],
"lastName":capitalize,
"state":capitalize,
"country": [capitalize,required],
"industry":capitalize,
"System_Type__c":capitalize,
"AccountType":capitalize,
"customerSegment":capitalize,
}
```

i wrote the below to achieve the str title but is there a way to apply it to the df columns without naming them all

```
def capitalize (column,df_temp):
    if df_temp[column].notna():
        df_temp[column]=df[column].str.title()
    return df_temp
```

What would be the best way to reference the dictionary function mapping to apply `str.title()` to all of the contents in the columns with a function "capitalize"?

desired output

```
data= [["English","John","Smith","Ohio","United States","","","Manufacturing","National","Residental","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

  Communication_Language__c firstName lastName state        country company email       industry System_Type__c AccountType customerSegment Existing_Customer__c GDPR_Email_Permission__c
0                   English      John    Smith  Ohio  United States                Manufacturing       National  Residental
```

Comment: What do you think `if df_temp[column].notna():` is doing?

Comment: Finding all the empty df columns and ignoring them since I only want to run my function on columns that have contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use apply for this, e.g.

```
cols_to_capitalize = list(parsing_map.keys())
df[cols_to_capitalize] = df[cols_to_capitalize].apply(lambda x: x.str.title())
```

If you want to keep your method dictionary, I would suggest that you write the methods to act on a column, not on the dataframe. Something like this:

```
data= [["English","john","smith","ohio","united states","","","manufacturing","National","Residental","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Communication_Language__c','firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

def capitalize(col):
    # TODO handle nan values
    # Maybe use any() instead of all()?
    # This code ignores any column that has even a single NaN value
    if col.notna().all():
        return col.str.title()
    return col

def required(col):
    # TODO do stuff
    return col

parsing_map={
    "firstName":[capitalize,required],
    "lastName":[capitalize],
    "state":[capitalize],
    "country": [capitalize,required],
    "industry":[capitalize],
    "System_Type__c":[capitalize],
    "AccountType":[capitalize],
    "customerSegment":[capitalize],
}


for col_name, fns in parsing_map.items():
    for fn in fns:
        df[col_name] = fn(df[col_name])
```

You could also pass in the full df into these methods if they need to access other columns, but still returning only the single column would make the design clearer.

But you should think carefully whether you really need to reinvent the `.apply` functionality.

Comment: Maybe use `any()` instead of `all()`? Right now, you're ignoring any column that has even a single NaN value~

Comment: I wasn't sure what the intention of the .notna line in the question was, but you're right. I've added your comment as a TODO to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Create a list of columns you want to include and then use apply

```
cols = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'country', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment']
df.apply(lambda col: col.replace(np.NaN, "").str.title() if col.name in cols else col)
```

EDIT: Yes, but put a string instead of a reference to your function in your parsing_map

```
parsing_map = {
    "firstName": "capitalize",
    "lastName": "capitalize",
    "state": "capitalize",
    "country": "capitalize",
    "industry": "capitalize",
    "System_Type__c": "capitalize",
    "AccountType": "capitalize",
    "customerSegment": "capitalize",
}

df.apply(lambda col: col.replace(np.NaN, "").str.title() if parsing_map.get(col.name) == "capitalize" else col)
```

If you use a dict with lists as values

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.replace(np.NaN, "").str.title() if "capitalize" in parsing_map.get(col.name) else col)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this utilizing the dictionary the maps the column names to a function already instead of making a new list

Comment: Yes, but put a string instead of a reference to your function in your parsing_map. Edited to show an example

Answer (score 0):

```
def capitalize(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.title()
    return df
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to this answer. This solution is the most simple (which is good). Note that `df[col].str.title()` will already ignore NaN values. You may also want to update the answer to more closely match the question so that the function also accepts a column and only capitalizes that column.